# Can we have all classes that can be partitioned into non-singleton finite sets, be sets?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory

Working in a suitable extension of $\sf ZF-Reg.$, can we have a transitive model $M$ of $\sf ZF-Reg.$ such that for every set in $M$ there is a partition on it in $M$ all compartments of which are non-singleton finite sets. And such that any subset $X$ of $M$ that is a family of pairwise disjoint larger than singleton finite sets then $X \in M$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not possible: the ordinals of $M$ will always provide a counterexample.

Even if regularity fails, the class $\mathsf{Ord}$ of ordinals cannot be a set. But we can partition $\mathsf{Ord}$ into (say) two-element sets via the equivalence relation $$\alpha\sim\beta\quad\iff\quad \sup\{\lambda: 2\cdot\lambda<\alpha\}=\sup\{\lambda: 2\cdot\lambda<\beta\}.$$ The classes of this relation are $\{0,1\},\{2,3\},...,\{\omega,\omega+1\}, ...$ etc.

(Perhaps more elegantly, let $\approx$ be any equivalence relation on $\omega$ all of whose classes are finite and have at least two elements. Then consider the relation $\approx'$ defined by $\alpha\approx'\beta$ iff there is a limit ordinal $\lambda$ and finite ordinals $m,n$ such that $\lambda+m=\alpha$, $\lambda+n=\beta$, and $m\approx n$.)

Comment: Yes! I had the feel that well ordered sets can violate what I'm saying, I think we need to require $X$ being non-well orderable, for this to be possible. So, the idea is that all non-well orderable classes of pairwise disjoint larger than singleton finite sets is a set.

Comment: I'll post that as a new question.

Comment: Is the last condition supposed to be $m\approx n$?

Comment: @AlecRhea Whoops, fixed!